# CSS3 DropShadow On Pages

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a drop shadow below each section/page of the website but am having problems doing so.

Demo of site: http://www.sfu.ca/~jca41/stuph/test/parallax01/parallax01.html

HTML:

```
<section id="first" class="page shadow">        
  <article>first page</article> </section>
<section id="second" class="page shadow">
  <article>second page</article> </section>
<section id="third" class="page shadow">        
  <article>third page</article> </section>  
<section id="fourth" class="page shadow">
  <article>fourth page</article> </section>
```

CSS:

```
.page { height: 1000px; }
.shadow {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 10px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 10px #000;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 10px #000;
}
#first { background: url(img/01.png) no-repeat fixed; }
#second { background: url(img/02.jpg) no-repeat fixed; }
#third { background: url(img/03.jpg) no-repeat fixed; }
#fourth { background: url(img/04.jpg) no-repeat fixed; }
```

Comment: it seems to work,  which browser are you testing on, what were you expecting?

Comment: The shadow is there, but it's being covered by the next section.

Comment: I have been testing on Chrome. I have tried adding `z-index` to each page id, but it does not work. How would I prevent the sections from covering it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add position: relative to your page class and then add z-index to each section so that the one on the top has bigger z-index than the one below.